# URL finding by email address not working with FriendlyId

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, friendly-id

I have the friendly_id gem installed (version 5.1.0) and have implemented the steps in the documentation to extend my model, add the slug field to the table, etc.  This url works as expected:

```
http://localhost:3000/owners/1
```

I'm trying to find by email address but look how the trailing .com is being treated:

```
http://localhost:3000/owners/me@example.com

{"id"=>"me@example",
 "format"=>"com"}
```

And since my client is really looking to receive the results of the find in json format, the client should be sending this URL to the server:

```
http://localhost:3000/me@example.com.json
```

but Rails doesn't like that:

```
No route matches [GET] "/owners/me@example.com.json"
```

where as

```
http://localhost:3000/owners/1.json
```

returns the json view as expected.

How (or what) should I code to get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, It's a not a friendly_id problem. Your controller is not called at all because you have a URL (`/owners/me@example.com/me@example.com`) that doesn't satisfy any of your routes in `config/routes.rb`.

It's because of ".com" in the end of the path. You should add a constraint to tell Rails that you will have an email as a part of url. I've created a small project with the following routing:

```
get "/:email", :to => "application#test", :constraints => { :email => /.+@.+\..*/ }
```

And controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  def test
    respond_to do |format|
      format.any { render :json => { :hello => params[:email] } }
    end
  end
end
```

And after it I'm able to call it using curl:

```
curl -H "Accept: application/json" http://localhost:3000/boo@example.com
```

Result:

```
{"hello":"boo@example.com"}
```

Comment: Your exact setup works, so I've accepted the answer and express my thanks for the assistance you've given.  When I try to have this action be caught by my owners controller Rails digs into the superclass and instead of looking up params[:email] it looks up params[:id] so I'll keep playing with this.

Comment: My bad: I had to alter the route to be get "owners/:email" etc. instead of just get "/:email"   --- thanks so much!!!